# Jacoco coverage report in spite of connected device test failures?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, jacoco

I'm cleaning up an Android project that has several hundred Espresso tests of which several are flaky. Getting 100% instrumented test success on a regular basis isn't realistic in this context.

My Gradle task for Jacoco code coverage works perfectly (!) when all the Espresso tests do pass (achievable by skipping the flaky ones). When there are test failures, however, the Jacoco report shows 0% coverage even though the Gradle test report has the correct data. Looks like the coverage.ec file generated is 0 bytes.

The `connected<flavor>DebugAndroidTest` task has been configured with `ignoreFailures = true`, so the build no longer halts when there were failing tests.

Is there any way to get the test task to correctly generate the coverage.ec file in spite of failures?

Comment: did you try to start the missing step when test has failed? `createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport`

Comment: That step is being run, it's just providing empty results.

Comment: @Turnsole did you find any solution of this issue, I am also facing the same issue?